# Why should I use a ROS plugin instead of the GAZEBO camera?

Tags: gazebo-11

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I want to simulate a 3D depth camera, but I allways find tutorials for a ROS plugin.
Is there a reason to use only the plugin or is the normal gazebo camera also viable?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/26136/why-should-i-use-a-ros-plugin-instead-of-the-gazebo-camera?/) by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 64 on 2020-11-27

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on 2021-01-20**:
As far as I have found out, the ROS plugin can send a ros message to a ros node.
The normal gazebo depth camera will only write in the console but will not publish to any ros node whatsoever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The ROS plugin just offers a ROS api for the gazebo camera, it doesn't do much work besides that. If you want to use the gazebo plugin without ros, you'll need to write a gazebo plugin in C++, or use ignition/gazebo transport (which also only exists for C++). But in short, you do not need ros, it's just very common.

---

Originally posted by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) with karma: 768 on 2020-11-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on 2020-11-28**:
Thank you for your answer.
So there is no pre-build ready to use Gazebo depth camera?
Do you know any good tutorials to use a depth camera in gazebo? The official tutorial from the get started page was a bit short and also only for ROS.

**Comment by [Peter Mitrano](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1068/peter-mitrano/) on 2020-12-11**:
You can follow that tutorial to set up the gazebo sensor, and then write your own plugin. I don't know of any tutorials, sorry. But the ros plugin code should be good reference for you, or perhaps this: https://github.com/intel/gazebo-realsense

**Comment by [Zeckurbo](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/36410/zeckurbo/) on 2020-12-17**:
Thank you very much